# iOS 15 - disable vibration for notification of all apps except phone calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, vibrate

How do I disable vibration for notification of all apps except phone calls on iOS 15?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Settings** -> **Sounds & Haptics** and scroll down to the **SOUNDS AND VIBRATION PATTERNS SECTION**.

Then go into each individual option (apart from Ringtone), go to **Vibration** and set it to **None**.

For individual applications, you will have to go to **Settings**, **Notifications**, go into each app and turn **Sounds** off.

Comment: Thank you, this works but it takes a lot of effort to disable vibration for every app manually. Is there a better way?

Comment: @TeddyC Unfortunately not